# Why does PIE *weydtos give PGmc wīsaz not wīssaz?

Tags: proto-indo-european, proto-germanic

Why does PIE *wey**dt**os give PGmc wī**s**az not wīssaz?

compare Pgmc *sta**ss**iz, *gawi**ss**iz, *kwi**ss**iz

Comment: my guess would be that the preceding long vowel had something to do with it (the other examples all have a short vowel before the ss), but I don't have any particular source or other supporting evidence

Comment: @Tristan You’re absolutely right – it’s a well-established development in Germanic (I added an answer which has more details).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably did, but one of the last phonological changes that happened to create what we call ‘Proto-Germanic’ was that long **ss* was reduced to short **s* after long vowels or diphthongs. More controversially (but no less correctly if you ask me), this didn’t apply to just **s(s)*, but to any geminate, resulting in the loss of overlong syllables in Proto-Germanic. This latter, less canonical, viewpoint is part of [Kluge’s Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kluge%27s_law).

Examples with **ss* include, giving a (Post-)PIE form a pre-PG form, and the ‘classical’ PG form:

- **h₁ēd-tos* > **ēssaz* > **ēsaz* ‘food, carrion’
- **koi̯d-tis* > **haissiz* > **haisiz* ‘command’ (same root as **haitaną* ‘call’)
- **u̯ei̯d-tos* > **wīssaz* > **wīsaz* ‘wise’

Examples with other consonants include:

- **dʰeu̯bʰ-no-* > **deupna-* > **deuppa-* > **deupa-*
- **dʰei̯gʰ-[n?]o-* > **dīkka-* > **dīka-*

There aren’t many exactly parallel cases, but there are some. As you can read about briefly in the Wikipedia article linked to above - and in more detail in [Guus Kroonen’s PhD dissertation](https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A2933146/view) – the issue has been mired in controversy for over a century.

Not, however, when it comes to **ss* becoming **s* after long vowels and diphthongs – that bit is pretty universally accepted.

Comment: how does this shortening of overlong syllables relate to the overlong vowels? Would it have to have occurred before the formation of such vowels?

Comment: @Tristan That’s a good question. Given how little we know about the actual practicalities of overlong vowels in PG, I don’t think we can say for sure. Personally, I suspect that the single overlong vowels did indeed come about later and weren’t necessarily a thing for very long before they were then shortened and merged with the regular long vowels (except word-finally). At the stage just prior to ‘classical’ PG when overlong syllables were lost, I think the ‘overlong’ vowels were likely still disyllabic sequences of long + short identical vowel.